# How to modify the default location where the python script is trying to write the log

Tags: python, file-io, output

There is a python script which I have to run in the background when performing some evaluations. However, the script tries saves some log throughout the process, and since I have to run it in a machine where I don't have sudo rights, the script doesn't get executed.

I think the line which causes the problem is:

```
parser.add_option("-L", "--logfile", dest="logfile", default=os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "log-name.log"), help="log messages to LOGFILE [default: %default]", metavar="LOGFILE")
```

I think I need to change the default location: `default=os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "log-name.log")`. How do I make it the output path to be a folder within my home directory. There I would not get any issue related to priviledge escalation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract your home directory from the environment:

```
from os.path import expanduser
homedir = expanduser("~")
parser.add_option("-L", "--logfile", dest="logfile", default=os.path.join(homedir, "log-name.log"), help="log messages to LOGFILE [default: %default]", metavar="LOGFILE")
```

Also, you can try adding a timestamp in your logfile's name so you don't overwrite existing logs by an accident.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
_OUTPATH = 'Users/username/logs'
...
parser.add_option("-L", "--logfile", dest="logfile", default=os.path.join(_OUTPATH, "log-name.log"), help="log messages to LOGFILE [default: %default]", metavar="LOGFILE")
```